# python zipfile module with TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, string, types, zip, readline

I wrote the following piece of code to read a text file inside of a zipped directory.  Since I don't want the output in bytes I added the TextIOWrapper to display the output as a string.  Assuming that this is the right way to read a zip file line by line (if it isn't let me know), then why does the output print a blank line?  Is there any way to get rid of it?

```
import zipfile
import io

def test():
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\zip1.zip')
    for filename in zf.namelist():
        words = io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(filename, 'r'))
        for line in words:
            print (line)
    zf.close()

test()

>>> 
This is a test line...

This is a test line...
>>> 

The two lines in the file inside of the zipped folder are:
This is a test line...
This is a test line...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zipfile.open` opens the zipped file in binary mode, which doesn't strip out carriage returns (i.e. '\r'), and neither did the defaults for `TextIOWrapper` in my test. Try configuring `TextIOWrapper` to use universal newlines (i.e. `newline=None`):

```
import zipfile
import io

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('data/test_zip.zip')
for filename in zf.namelist():
    with zf.open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words = io.TextIOWrapper(f, newline=None)
        for line in words:
            print(repr(line))
```

Output:

```
'This is a test line...\n'
'This is a test line...'
```

The normal behavior when iterating a file by line in Python is to retain the newline at the end. The `print` function also adds a newline, so you'll get a blank line. To just print the file you could instead use `print(words.read())`. Or you could use the `end` option of the print function: `print(line, end='')`.